# catching memory access violation using try and catch blocks in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to know how to catch memory access violations using try and catch.

for example I have an CStringArray of 2Strings. If,by mistake,program try to access 3rd string from this CStringArray, it will crashing. 
my question is how to catch this violation and avoid program crashing...

thank u all

Comment: You can't. The best you can do is register a signal handler, depending on your OS. And even then, the only sane thing to do is clean up and exit, generally.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Try/catch is used to catch C++ exceptions. Memory access violation is not a C++ exception but a hardware exception.